# ReactiveForm inside an NgFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a ngFor that has inside a reactiveForm. This is the code:

```
<div class="element-list">
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" class="single-item" *ngFor="let p of points; let i = index">
            <span>Lat: </span> <input formControlName="lat" type="text" value="{{p.lat}}">
            <span>Lon: </span> <input formControlName="lon" type="text" value="{{p.lon}}">
            <a (click)="updateData(i)">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

this is .ts side

```
export class MapInfoBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
  points: MapDetailModel[] = [];
  isAlive = true;
  formGroup: FormGroup;


  constructor(
    private mapService: MapService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ){}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.mapService.pointsChanged
    .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
    .subscribe( evt => {
      if(!!evt){
        this.points = evt;
      }
    });

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      lat: new FormControl(),
      lon: new FormControl()
    });
  }


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isAlive = false;
  }

  updateData(id: number){
    console.log(id + " > " + this.formGroup.value);
  }
}
```

Whenever I click the `a`, what i get from `this.formGroup.value` is just null & null value.

**The question**

My quesiton is, how to "know" which formGroup I'm referring whenever i click on a button? `this.points` change sometimes, with new element pushed from another component.

I'd like to update, for example, the third element, and see in the `console.log` the updated values.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**How I solved this problem**

Thank's to @ak.leimrey for passing me that link below.

Here's how i solved:

.ts file:

```
export class MapInfoBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
  points: MapDetailModel[] = [];
  isAlive = true;
  survey: FormGroup;
  items = false;

  constructor(
    private mapService: MapService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ){}

  ngOnInit() {



    this.mapService.pointsChanged
    .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
    .subscribe( evt => {
      if(!!evt){
        this.points = evt;

        if(!this.items){
          this.survey = this.fb.group({
            sections: this.fb.array([
              this.initSection(0),
            ]),
          });
          this.items = true;
        } else {
          this.addSection(this.points.length - 1);
        }
      }
    });
  }


  initSection(idx: number) {
    return this.fb.group({
      lat: [this.points[idx].lat],
      lon: [this.points[idx].lon],
    })
  }

  addSection(idx: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.survey.get('sections');
    control.push(this.initSection(idx));
  }

  getSections(form) {
    //console.log(form.get('sections').controls);
    return form.controls.sections.controls;
  }

  updateData(index: number){
    const values = this.survey.value.sections[index] as MapDetailModel;
    this.mapService.setChangePoint(values);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isAlive = false;
  }
}
```

html file:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="map-info-bar">
        <div class="blocco-info">
            {{lang.phrase('Coord')}}: {{lang.phrase('Lat')}} {{currentLatitude}} {{lang.phrase('Lon')}} {{currentLongitude}}
        </div>
        <div class="blocco-info">
            <dx-select-box [items]="zoomLevels" [value]="scale" (onValueChanged)="onScaleChange($event.value)">
            </dx-select-box>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element-list">
        <form [formGroup]="survey" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(survey)" *ngIf="items">
            <div formArrayName="sections">
                <div class="single-item" *ngFor="let section of getSections(survey); let i = index">
                    <div  [formGroupName]="i">
                        <input type="text" formControlName="lat" class="frm-txt">
                        <input type="text" formControlName="lon" class="frm-txt">
                        <a (click)="updateData(i)">Update data</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Class:

```
export class MapDetailModel{
    lat: number;
    lon: number;
    alt: number;
    long?: number;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to look into formarray instead of formgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate being 'that' guy, but I feel this code example is among the best to not only explain how nested forms work, but also how to reference single items in a form.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Well this is the only thing that helped me out solving my problem. Thank you dude.

Comment: Keep that link alive for anyone who is struggling with the same concept. It was also what helped me understand reactive forms better. It beats most explanations and examples, in my opinion at least. Thank you, and happy coding.

Comment: I had to simplify it a bit, I've deleted like 90% of the code to understand properly, but it worked out. I've mentioned you and your answer in my edit so this link will be alive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe helps you.
just look the code and then make changes, don't copy and paste just **read**

#### on your ts code.

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
   this.initForm():
}

initForm() {

     this.form = new FormGroup({
        num_weeks: new FormControl(1, []),
        metric: new FormControl('sales', []),
        statistic: new FormControl('min', []),
        filters: filters
      });
}
```

#### on your HTML component

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
           <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="never" style="width: 360px; font-size: 14px;">
          <mat-label>Metric</mat-label>
          <mat-select #timeRange formControlName="metric" placeholder="Time range" placeholder="Type">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">
              {{ type.name }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="never" style="width: 360px; font-size: 14px;">
          <mat-label>Statistic</mat-label>
          <mat-select #timeRange formControlName="statistic" placeholder="" placeholder="Statistic">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let statistic of statistics" [value]="statistic.value">
              {{ statistic.name }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to the fact that all the `formControlName` have the same values inside the `ngFor`.

Try at first:

```
<span>Lat: </span> <input formControlName="lat{{i}}" type="text" value="{{p.lat}}">
<span>Lon: </span> <input formControlName="lon{{i}}" type="text" value="{{p.lon}}">
```

Then, create each `lon` and `lat` in the `formGroup`:

```
this.points.forEach((point,index) => {
   this.formGroup.addControl("lat" + index, new FormControl());
   this.formGroup.addControl("lon" + index, new FormControl());
 });
```

And you will be able to access each controls.